Isn't this proof by induction wrong?? The question asks to prove a weak inequality, and the answer yields a strict inequality.
Question:
Prove that for all ( $n \geq 1 $),
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Solution Attempt:
We will use mathematical induction to prove that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Base Case: For ( n = 1 ),
$$
\sum_{i=1}^1 \frac{1}{i^2} = 1 \leq 2 - \frac{1}{1} = 1.
$$
The base case holds.
Induction Step: Assume that the inequality holds for some ( $n \geq 1$ ), that is,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n}.
$$
We need to prove that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
Starting from the assumption,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}.
$$
Using the induction hypothesis, we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}.
$$
Then,
$$
2 - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < 2 - \frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
Problem:
Notice that in the final inequality, we actually get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i^2} < 2 - \frac{1}{n+1}.
$$

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

@JoséCarlosSantos oh sorry, should i change it now?

If not now, when?

I've replaced your first image by a MathJax formula. The rest is up to you.

If $A < B$ then it's also true that $A \leq B$.

@aschepler but 3<4 while 3≤4 is not true

Hm? $3 \leq 4$ is true.

@UmbertoDenayer it is ...recall the definition of $\leq$

Goodness me! I need to do some more revision.

but you have equality in the base case. so you have $\le$ for the overall proof anyway

You should read $\le$ as "less than OR equal to". In maths as in computer programming, if either side of that OR is true, the $\le$ is true. Hence $3 \le 4$ is true, as is $4 \le 4$.
Thus if you had proved that $f < A$, you would indeed also have proved $f \le A$.
However, in your case, you have proved (assuming, I didn't check your proof) that the summation is

less than (for $n > 1$), OR
equal to (for $n = 1$)

Hence you have indeed proved that the summation is "less than OR equal to", but not that it is "strictly less than".
