Changing from $>$ to $\geq$ during inductive proofs
I am trying to solve the following question:

Prove by induction that for every integer $n\geq 2,$ $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n}\geq \frac{7}{12}$$

I verified the statement is true for $n=2$, for which the statement changes into an equality.
I did manage to progress a bit in the Inductive Step, since if the statement is true for $k$, where $k\geq 2$, then
$$\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2k}\geq\frac{7}{12}\\
\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2k+2}\geq\frac{7}{12}-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2k+2}\\
\frac{1}{(k+1)+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2(k+1)-2}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)-1}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}\geq\frac{7}{12}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}
\end{gather*}
$$
However, at this point I have some doubts. I want to finish the Inductive Step by showing that $$\frac{7}{12}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\geq\frac{7}{12}$$
but I can only show that left-hand side is strictly greater than the right-hand side.
My general question is: In this case or in similar inductive proofs, would it fine to change the sign from $>$ to $\geq$? It seems possible, since $\geq$ means "greater than OR equal to" and the original inequality does change into an equality at $n=2$ (but not for $n\geq 3$, which is probably why this issue arises), but I have never seen anyone change signs like this in inductive proofs.

Not entirely sure what you mean.  Obviously if you can prove that $F(n )>G(n)$ then you have shown that $F(n)≥G(n)$.  But if you want to show the stronger statement inductively, then you need a base case for which the stronger claim holds.

I think you’re getting a little bit lost in the symbols here. If $a>b$, is $a\geq b$? To figure this out just like, think about what “greater than OR equal to” means.

Are you claiming that, for $n>2$, we actually have $F(n)>G(n)$?  If so, then I'd say it is worth proving that one.  To do it inductively you'd probably want a base case for which it actually held, but it's easy to check that it holds for $n=3$ so there's no problem there.

@lulu I played around with the sides of the question's inequality in Desmos, and it does seem to me that for $n>2$, it is $F(n)>G(n)$ (assuming $F(n)$ is the left-hand side of the question's inequality and $G(n)$ - the right-hand side).

@lulu This is the approach I am leaning to right now (proving inductively for $n>2$), but I was just curious if changing signs from $>$ to $\geq$ is allowed to avoid splitting this proof in cases.

@Tom you don’t need to “change the sign.” You just, have simply proved what you wanted to. It is TRUE that $7/12+x\geq 7/12$ (for $x>0$), which is what you showed and what you wanted to show.

@Malady I think I am a bit lost, to be honest. When I was asking this question I thought of things like $2>1$ and $1>0$, which are true, but so are $2\geq 1$ or $1\geq 0$ (I think). So, I thought maybe I could use the same logic in my proof.

Just as a matter of logic:  if you have $F(2)≥G(2)$ and you can prove that $F(n)≥G(n)\implies F(n+1)>G(n+1)$ then you are done.

@Malady Aaah, I see. This was exactly my question. Thank you for clarifying!

@lulu Aaah, right! How could I miss that? Thank you for this insight!

$x>y$ implies $x \geq y$ by definition. The equality only holds for the case $n=2$ as you've correctly deduced.

@CyclotomicField Thank you for your comment!

Very similar question asked just yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4990842/isnt-this-proof-by-induction-wrong-the-question-asks-to-prove-a-weak-inequali

As indicated by the comments, there is a standard approach to math problems similar to the posted question.
Suppose that :

The function $~f(n)~$ is defined for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.~$

You know that $~f(2) \geq A,~$ where $~A~$ is some constant.

You are trying to prove, by induction, the conjecture that $~f(n) \geq A,~$ for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.~$


It is possible that the conjecture is true, without $~f(n)~$ being a strictly increasing function.  However, if $~f(n)~$ happens to be a strictly increasing function, then you could reason as follows:

The conjecture is true for $~n=2.$ 
That is, $~f(2) \geq A.$

Suppose that the conjecture is true for $~n = N,~$ where $~N \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$ 
Then, since $~f(n)~$ is strictly increasing, you have that $~f(N+1) > f(N) \geq A.$


I emphasize that the conjecture might still be true if $~f(n)~$ is not strictly increasing.  So, you have that $~f(n)~$ being strictly increasing is not a necessary condition for the conjecture to be true, but it is a sufficient condition for the conjecture to be true.
Since, in this instance, $~f(n)~$ is a strictly increasing function, the entire problem reduces to proving that.
Generally, there are two ways that you might prove this:

If $~f(2)~$ happens to be positive, then you could simply prove that $~\dfrac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} > 1,~$ for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$

Alternatively, you could prove that $~f(n+1) - f(n) > 0,~$ for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$


The approach in the second bullet point above is the easiest for this particular math problem.
Rather than showing an answer, I will show a solution, which includes an intuitive derivation of the answer.
Consider the specific value
$$f(5) - f(4) = \left[ ~\frac{1}{6} + \cdots + \frac{1}{10} ~\right] - \left[ ~\frac{1}{5} + \cdots + \frac{1}{8} ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{5}$$
$$= \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{10} - \frac{2}{10}$$
$$= \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{10} > 0. \tag1 $$
So, you have that if the conjecture happens to be true for $~N = 4~$ [i.e. that $~f(4) \geq A$], then you can reason that $~f(5) > f(4) \geq A.$
Then, you reason that when $~n=4,~$ that $~f(5) - f(4)~$ turns out to equal
$$\frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2},$$
which is positive specifically because
$$(2n+1) < (2n+2).$$
Then, you realize that the entire problem reduces to showing that for any $~N \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ that
$$f(N+1) - f(N) = \frac{1}{2N+1} - \frac{1}{2N+2}. \tag2 $$
So, the entire problem reduces to showing that the assertion in (2) above is true.
Using the intuition developed by considering the specific case of $~f(5) - f(4),~$ the assertion in (2) above can be shown as follows:
$$f(N+1) - f(N)$$
$$= \left[ ~\frac{1}{N+2} + \frac{1}{N+3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2N+2} ~\right]$$
$$- \left[ ~\frac{1}{N+1} + \frac{1}{N+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2N} ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{1}{2N+1} + \frac{1}{2N+2} - \frac{1}{N+1}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2N+1} + \frac{1}{2N+2} - \frac{2}{2N+2}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2N+1} - \frac{1}{2N+2} > 0.$$
